# C++ , how to return a reference to the member variable from iterator

Tags: c++, vector, reference, iterator, set

There is the following class B derived from std::vector

```
class B: public std::vector <unsigned int>
{
    public:
            B() : std::vector <unsigned int> ( 0 ) {}
};
```

and a class A witten as follows:

```
class A
{
    private:        
            B b;    
    double x;

public:
    B & getB () {return b;}
    B const & getB() const {return b;}

    bool operator() ( const A & a ) const
            {
                    return a < a.x;
            }
};
```

Why it is impossible to return a refererence to the variable b of some object A stored in std::list from its iterator (and how to do that)?

```
int main ()
{
std::set <A > alist;
std::set <A> ::iterator i_alist = alist.begin();

for (; i_alist != alist.end(); i_list++)
{
    B &il = (*i_alist).getB(); //Compiler error
    B &il2 = i_alist->getB(); //Compiler error

    il.push_back(10);   //Modify il and concurrently B
}
}
```

Compiler error:

```
Error   1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const B' to 'B &'    d:\test.cpp
```

Thanks for your help...

**Edit question**:

The possible solution using const_cast :

```
B &il2 = const_cast <B&> ( i_alist->getB() );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has very little to do with `std::vector` and everything to do with `std::set`. You store your objects in a `std::set`. Elements of `std::set` are not modifiable from the outside. Once you inserted an element into a set, you cannot change it.

For this reason, `std::set::iterator` might (and will) evaluate to a constant object, even if it is not a `const_iterator` (the language specification actually allows `std::set::iterator` and `std::set::const_iterator` to refer to the same type, but does not require it). I.e. in your example `*i_list` is a const-qualified object of type `const A`. The compiler will call the `const` version of `getB`, which returns `const B &`. You are apparently hoping to break through that constness, expecting the non-const version of `getB` to be called.

There's no way around it, unless you decide to use some sort of hack (`const_cast` etc.) to remove the constness from the set element and thus make the compiler to call non-const version of `getB`.

The `const_cast`-based hack-solution would look as

```
B &il = const_cast<A &>(*i_alist).getB();
```

or you can remove the constness later, from the returned `B` reference

```
B &il = const_cast<B &>((*i_alist).getB());
B &il2 = const_cast<B &>(i_alist->getB());
```

Comment: Personally I think it was a mistake by the C++ standard to force constness on a `set` key. I often have complex objects in a set whose contents may be changed without affecting the ordering. And wasn't this a change introduced by C++11?

Comment: @ AndreyT: Is there any way how to allow the object stored in std::set to be modifiable from the outsdide? For example using a const_cast?

Comment: @Mark Ransom: The constness of the key proper makes sense, but the need to modify the non-key parts of the object do arise pretty often. Yeah, I agree, set elements should be modifiable.

Comment: @MarkRansom, but how would `std::set` possible gurantee that your change doesn't affect ordering?

Comment: @aleguna: It wouldn't (maybe some assertions in debug implementation). It would simply say "know what you are doing and do it at your own risk".

Comment: @AndreyT, if you know what you are doing, then you can declare the member you want to modify `mutable`. This at least will ring some bells to the person reading your code.

Comment: @aleguna, declaring members `mutable` means that you've given up the ability to use `const` in the way it was intended. Sometimes you really do want `const` access to members of a set.

Comment: @MarkRansom, but modifying keys in itself sort of defeats the point of having an ordered set, no?

Comment: @aleguna, assuming the entire object is the "key" doesn't match every useful use-case for `set`. Ideally what you want is some parts const and some parts not, but C++ doesn't give you that granularity.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks for remembering me - maybe this isn't even a useful use-case for a `std::set` at all. See my Answer.

Comment: @aleguna: If some type was introduced solely for the purpose of serving as a `set::set` element, then `mutable` would be a fairly acceptable solution. Not good, but acceptable. But declaring member of some completely independent type as `mutable` just because somewhere in the program it happens to be stored in some `std::set` is catastrophically bad design. Object are not supposed to "know" that they might be stored in a `std::set`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that look weird about your example:

1. Never derive from `std::vector`. It's not designed for that use. And there normally is no reason to do so, except laziness, i.e. to avoid some typing.
2. What is that `A::operator()` for? Looks like some strange way to provide a Comparator for the `std::set` you are using. Normally you don't alter a class just because you stuff it into a `std::set` somewhere. If you really want to be able to compare your A's (generally, not just for the set), then write a proper free `bool operator<(A const&, A const&);` If it's just for the set, write a custom Comparator in the place where you use the set. (That comparator should not need to access A's privates)
3. What is the `A::x` used for? Only for comparison or even only for the comparison inside the set? If it's just that, consider to use a `std::map<double, A>` or even a `std::map<double, B>` where you put your x as the keys and the actual objects as the values.

You see, there are a lot of open questions I ask, and maybe the solution (using a map) does not even fit your problem. That is because you did not show us the *real* code you have but only some example with meaningless names. So we only see what you are trying to *do*, not what you actually want to *achieve* with your code.

**PS:** maybe you don't even need an ordered container in the first place, it could suffice to stuff all the objects into a `std::vector` and then `std::sort` it. Depends on the kind of objects you really have (the A's of your example are cheap to copy/swap) and of the ways you use the container - how the insertions are interleaved with the loops and so on.